# How to use onBeforeRouteEnter in setup() Vue 3 composition API?

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
  $store.dispatch('PartnersModule/fetchPartnerById', id).then( (resolve:contentInterface) =>{
                    if (resolve) {
                         content.value = resolve.info
                         employers.value = resolve.employers
                         branches.value = resolve.branches
                         contentLoading.value = false;
                    }
               }, error => {
                    contentLoading.value = false;
                    $router.push({name: String($route.meta.backRoute)})
                    console.error(error, "Error fetching list")
               }
          )
```

I got function which returns **Promise**.

If data by **id** was found route should enter, else I want to redirect back.

But there is no `onBeforeRouteEnter` function in **vue-router**.

I used, `onMounted` and `onBeforeMount` but they are same, component shows up and disappears if **promise** returned an **error**